Find general solution of $xu_x - yu_y - u + x^2y = 0$ using lagrange method
I need to find the general solution of $xu_x - yu_y - u + x^2y = 0$ with lagrange method
Here is what I have done:
we have $\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dy}{-y} = \frac{du}{u-x^2y}$
taking the first two memebers we get :
$$\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dy}{-y}\implies xy = c$$
now taking the last two we get:
$$\frac{dy}{-y} = \frac{du}{u-x^2y} \implies \frac{du}{dy} = -\frac{u}{y} + x^2$$
$\text{Multiply both sides by } y:$ $$y \frac{du}{dy} + u = yx^2 $$
solve the ODE:
$$(yu)_y = yx^2 \implies yu = \frac{x^2y^2}{2}+c_1 \implies 2yu - x^2y^2 = c_2$$
so we have that for some function $f$ we get:
$$f(xy) = 2yu-x^2y^2$$
lets isolate $u$ :
$$u = \frac{f(xy)+x^2y^2}{2y}$$
but now when I'm checking the solution i.e insert $u$ back to the PDE I'm getting:
$$x\frac{f'(xy)y+2xy^2}{2y}-y\frac{(f'(xy)x+2x^2y)2y-2(f(xy)+x^2y^2)}{4y^2}-\frac{f(xy)+x^2y^2}{2y}+x^2y = x^2y \neq 0 $$
so clearly I made a mistake, I tried taking the first and last members from the lagrange auxiliary equastion but I got the same thing.

$u(x,y)=x\cdot f(x y)- \ln(x)\cdot x y^2$

$$(yu)_y = yx^2 \implies yu = \frac{x^2y^2}{2}+c_1 \quad\text{is FALSE}$$
One cannot integrate $yx^2$ wrt $y$ because $x$ isn't constant. $x$ is function of $y$.
From the first characteristic equation $x=\frac{c}{y}$
$$(yu)_y = yx^2=y\left(\frac{c}{y}\right)^2=\frac{c^2}{y}$$
$$yu=c^2\ln|y|+c_1$$
$$u=c^2\frac{\ln(y)}{y}+\frac{c_1}{y}$$
$c_1=f(c)=f(xy)\quad$ with arbitrary function $f$.
$$u=(xy)^2\frac{\ln(y)}{y}+\frac{f(xy)}{y}$$
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=x^2y\ln|y|+\frac{f(xy)}{y}}$$
Or equivalently
$$u(x,y)=x^2y\ln|y|+xF(xy)$$
with $F$ an arbitrary function. $f(xy)=xyF(xy)$.
